# Is this a design pattern? Help me identify

Tags: design-patterns

I am trying to figure out if I unintentionally used a design pattern? Please help me out here.

I have a application which will generate events (event1 , event 2, ... eventn).

I have another library (Event Hanlder Library) where the event handling methods are written.

I use an interface (Communicator )  which  has method as "GenerateEvent" implemented by Event handler library.

Finally the main application which generates the events... uses reflection to load the event handler library and at runtime on the basis of event no, the event specific class (of Event Handler) is hooked. The main app uses the Interface method GenerateEvent to send events across

Is this a kind of design pattern as an interface is being used between two assemblies to work together? I could provide more details in term of pseudo code in case my explanation is not enough.

Edit: Would like to add, the result of the event is returned to the main application via the communicator Interface again which has another method SendResult() (from event handler to main app) . Now does this return functionality change the pattern?
Could it be possibly a factory design pattern. Dynamic loading (via reflection) + initialization of subclass depending upon event ??

Comment: @esimov For Interviews :) In case I hav used a design pattern, I must know. I am just all scared of design patterns I never get them. But in case this is some pattern here.. i will never forget it as I implemented it.

Answer (score 0):

Without the details, it's hard to answer with any degree of confidence, but since you mentioned reflection and looks like you have a publish/subscribe model it sounds similar to the an event bus, which is an implementation of the [Observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) pattern.

If you read that article, you will see that it mentions Publish/Subscribe as a pattern in itself, so the matter is definitely debatable which *exact* pattern you implemented :)

Answer (score 0):

This is [Observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) for event generation. Not sure about dynamic loading by reflection

Comment: Thanks. I think its a mix of Observer + factory pattern (dynamic loading-> subclass instantiation on demand). Do you think so?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to conclude on whether you have used the pattern rightly or not without having concrete details.Yeah as others mentioned looks like you have event based publisher-subscriber model, chances are there it could be observer pattern. Pls provide more info!!

Observer/Publisher-Subscriber pattern:
An object subscribes to another object’s specific activity and gets notified. The subscriber is also called observer, while the object being observed is called publisher or subject. The publisher notifies (calls) all the subscribers when an important event occurs and may often pass a message in the form of an event object.

Looks like your Communicator class is the publisher which is generating the event and event handler library which you have writtens are the subscribers!!

Comment: Very well explained. Thank you very much.